# Creating a cases environment

Tags: environments, cases, tabularray

I'm using the `tabularray` package to create a cases-like environment, with some changes:

1. I want the 'if' automatically placed.
2. I need two versions: with and without a star. The first one must change the 'if' for an 'otherwise' but only in the last row.
3. With an optional parameter that sets the first column alignment.

This is what I have for now:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {amssymb}   % for \mathbb
\usepackage   {mathtools} % for \coloneqq
\usepackage   {tabularray}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{jcases}{sO{c}} % s=star, O(c)=first column align, default c
{% At the beginning
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% with star
      \left\{\begin{tblr}
      {% format
         colspec={#2l}, column{2}={leftsep=0.2em},
         cell{1-Y}{2}={preto=\text{if}\hspace{0.7em}},
         cell{Z}{2}={l,preto=\text{otherwise.}}
      }
   }
   {% without star
      \left\{\begin{tblr}
      {% format
         colspec={#2l},
         column{2}={leftsep=0.2em,preto=\text{if}\hspace{0.7em}}
      }
   }
}% At the end
{\end{tblr}\right.}

\begin{document}
So now we define the Dirichlet function as
\begin{align*}
\chi_\mathbb{Q}(x) & \coloneqq{\begin{jcases}
0 & x\not\in\mathbb{Q},\\
1 & x\in\mathbb{Q}.
\end{jcases}}
\shortintertext{But it looks better this way:}
\chi_\mathbb{Q}(x) & \coloneqq{\begin{jcases}*
0 & x\not\in\mathbb{Q},\\
1 & x\in\mathbb{Q},\\
2
\end{jcases}}% tblr inside align must be enclosed in curly braces
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I think the image explains what I want to achieve:
[image]

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better/simpler/more robust way to do it?
2. Can I get exactly the same spacing as in a conventional `array`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a standard `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,amssymb}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{jcases}{O{c}}
 {%
  \left\lbrace
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% like in cases
  \begin{array}{@{} #1 >{\text{if }}l @{}}
 }
 {%
  \end{array}\right.
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{jcases*}{O{c}}
 {\begin{jcases}[#1]}
 {&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\text{otherwise}}\end{jcases}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)&=
\begin{jcases}
0 & x\not\in\mathbb{Q},\\
1 & x\in\mathbb{Q}.
\end{jcases}
\\
\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)&=
\begin{jcases*}
0 & x\not\in\mathbb{Q},\\
1 & x\in\mathbb{Q},\\
2
\end{jcases*}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like it! It's very simple. Thanks!!! :-)

Comment: +1 I like this a lot! However, I notice that the original question had a period (full stop) at the end of "otherwise", and this answer doesn't. (Grammatically, sometimes we might want a period there; other times we might want a comma, or semicolon, or...) Might I suggest adding another optional parameter to the `jcases*` environment definition, indicating what to put at the end of otherwise. That way a user could put, for instance, `\begin{jcases*}[.][r]` if they wanted the column of values to be right-justified and they wanted the last line to end with `otherwise.`

Comment: I had in mind something like this:

`\NewDocumentEnvironment{jcases*}{O{} O{c}}

 {\begin{jcases}[#2]}

 {&\multicolumn{1}{l}{\text{otherwise}#1}\end{jcases}}`